# Java code to create or write files in UTF-8, DOS and UNIX formats

Tags: java, unix, utf-8

I want to create files using Java in the formats specified in question, ie. UTF-8 for the chartset, and either DOS or UNIX format for the end of lines.

I tried lot of things and checked in `Context editor`, but it always showed me DOS format.
Code which I tried is:

```
Writer writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/home/aa.txt"),"UTF-8"));
        writer.write("Something");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      // report
    }
```

I even tried giving `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` and also `StandardCharsets.UTF-8`
but each and every time I get an output file in DOS format.

I also tried terminal commands like `dos2unix`, `sed` etc.
Is there any different solution for creating such file formats?

Comment: what is the difference between dos and unix text files?  CRLF only I thinks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by mixing character encoding (UTF-8) with OS names, but if DOS is to mean "ASCII with CRLF line endings" and Unix means "ASCII with LF line endings", then the trouble is that "Something" looks exactly the same in both UTF-8 and ASCII, and there's no line endings in it. What difference are you expecting to see?

Comment: No difference but i just want its format to be unix or utf-8 which doesn't change after my code

Comment: You are mixing line endings with character encoding. Please try to rephrase what you want.

Comment: The code sample in your question will have no line separators at all in it, so I'm not sure how it can be in any of the newline styles at all. `BufferedReader` only inserts the line separator when you call `newLine()`, so either don't call that method and write the desired line separator explicitly, or override `newLine()` in your own subclass to make the behaviour configurable.

Comment: Also, your code sample's output will only contain ASCII characters, which would make it impossible for, say, a text editor, to detect that it's supposed to be UTF-8. You could write out a byte-order-mark, but that can cause problems down the line - not every system that processes text will know to detect and handle it.

Comment: Is there any way wherein i can save the generated text file in utf format

Comment: bjk, what makes you think that the text you have written (i.e. "Something") is not stored in UTF-8? In other words, what test are you applying that would show you whether it's UTF-8 or not?

Comment: I am checking the generated text file in notepad++ also in conText editor. Also I checked the text file through notepad and did save as and acc to me if in save as option its by default showing format as UTF then the file is in UTF format. But i get ANSI as option

Comment: @bjk - That doesn't say anything about how the file is encoded, but about the heuristics the text editor uses to detect the encoding. The encoding of a text file is not saved anything in the file or in its filesystem metadata. The true test of whether a file is encoded as UTF-8 is: reading it using UTF-8 in an application, displaying the contents in the UI, and having it appear correctly. Preferrably with a file that contains non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @bjk I suggest skimming through material like [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) - notably the part that it is **impossible** to look at a string - or any other text - and know what encoding it's in, unless you're explicitly told what it is through some out-of-band means. For a "plain text" file on disk, it could be the byte-order-mark, or you can assume UTF-8 and call everyone who saves files using something else a moron.